# Netfliz zuul with Spring cloud zookeeper

Tags: apache-zookeeper, spring-cloud, netflix-zuul, service-discovery

I am working on a microservice architecture based application where I am implementing reverse proxy using netflix zuul. However, for service discovery, some other team has already implemented Spring cloud zookeeper. Can anyone please  explain how to make these two component work together. Basically, for every request that I get on my Zuul client, I should route be able to route it to the appropriate service using this service discovery mechanism. 
I have searched a lot over net for a good example for reference, but no luck.

Comment: Spring cloud zookeeper is not the service discovery mechanism from spring cloud. For service discovery, spring cloud uses eureka.

Comment: Check the link http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-zookeeper/1.1.1.RELEASE/  , it has details of how to use Zookeeper as service registry for Spring applications. You may also want to use Eureka, Consul etc. But you should first have some familiarity with the tech you are going to use for service discovery.